# How to target a running app with a KeyEvent?

Tags: android

my goal is to target with a keyevent a specific application running either in foreground or background from a background service.

I tried many solutions, but have not yet managed to do it.

The few solutions tried (all from a background running service):

---

With a broadcast, I tried to target the first application (for example the phone app) that would manage the key event

```
KeyEvent lKey1Up = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL);
KeyEvent lKey1Dwn = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL);
Intent lKey1UpIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
Intent lKey1DwnIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
lKey1UpIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, lKey1Up);
lKey1DwnIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, lKey1Dwn );
sendOrderedBroadcast(lKey1UpIntent, null);
sendOrderedBroadcast(lKey1DwnIntent, null);
```

=> Nothing happens with my foreground phone app when the broadcast is performed while I am in a phone call state (OFFHOOK). Indeed, I was nearly sure this would not work since I have no way to specificely target the phone app.

---

With ***Instrumentation***, I tried to target the application that has the focus :

```
Instrumentation lInst  = new Instrumentation();
KeyEvent lKey1Up = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1);
KeyEvent lKey1Dwn = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1);
lInst.sendKeySync(lKey1Up);
lInst.sendKeySync(lKey1Dwn);
```

also tried with a single call to :

```
lInst.sendKeyDownUpSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1)
```

=> Application crashes (also during phone call)
looks like I cannot use Instrumentation out of a testing purpose

---

Eventually, I thought about using

```
superDispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent)
```

but since I don't know how to target a specific window from the targeted running application (and I have none in my service, indeed), I don't know how to use it at all.

---

And before anyone asks, I added the

> android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS
>   android.permission.MODIY_PHONE_STATE

in my manifest in order to be sure all I do is "allowed".

Then... thanks first for reading until here, and now :

- some of you know how I can manage to
  do target a specific application with a
  keystroke event from a service?
- some of you know how to do the same with the phone application specificely?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I stopped working on iOs 2 years ago.. and never found out a "clean way to do it". But am quite sure this has evolved a lot since, and you may found new tricks nowaday

Answer (score 3):

> my goal is to target with a keyevent a specific application running either in foreground or background from a background service.

This is not possible, because it is a security hole. Allowing application A to inject key events into application B raises all sorts of ugly malware possibilities.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your reply. I feared such an answer. I will keep looking for a way to do it, but it definitely looks like I will never manage to do so

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this, but need **rooted device**:

```
public static void inputKeyEvent(String keyCodeString) {
    try {
        int keyCode = Integer.parseInt(keyCodeString);
        try {
            Instrumentation m_Instrumentation = new Instrumentation();
            m_Instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(keyCode);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            try {
                Process processKeyEvent = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/xbin/su");
                DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(processKeyEvent.getOutputStream());
                os.writeBytes("input keyevent " + keyCode + "\n");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```